# Vertically aligning text with CSS using the font's actual pixel height?

Tags: html, css, canvas, fonts

I need to vertically center text in the middle of an image, but the custom font I'm using has very large ascenders and descenders (i.e. parts of the letters stick out quite a lot), and so the vertical alignment is not equally correct for all possible characters.

For example, look at the difference in alignment between the characters `X` and `g`:

[image]

I know that this is because of the "baseline" of the font and that's not what my question is about.

I want to know if it is possible to vertically align a string of text using the actual pixel values of the font instead of relying on the "bounding box" or line height of the container - for example, align using the green boundaries below:

[image]

[image]

So using the above as an example, the single characters `X` and `g` would appear perfectly centered like this:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built-in way to do this.

The function [`measureText()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/measuretext) returns a [`TextMetric`](https://devdocs.io/dom/textmetrics) object that in the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#textmetrics) define all the necessary values to do so including `actualBounding*`, however and sadly, only `width` from that spec is [included in the browsers](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/cLa66f7x/).

There exist a [polyfill](https://github.com/motiz88/canvas-text-metrics-polyfill) that may help overcome some of these limitations, but I have never tried it myself and cannot say if it's good or not.

The last option is to actually scan lines to find out the pixel positions of each character. How well it works depends on how much text you need to render, if not too much the performance should be fine. You basically have to write each character to a offscreen canvas, then scan from top and bottom to find out where first pixels appears respectively, and use that as actual bounding box for top and bottom.

Comment: Thank you. I did wonder about the canvas pixel scanning thing. Do you know if there exists a library or script which does it already?

Comment: @WackGet consider accepting the answer if that gave answer to the question.

Comment: I will do, but I'm trying to pull together a final solution which directly answers the question which I can publish here. Thanks.